PHP-FPM application is suddenly becoming unresponsive until container restart
I’m maintaining a PHP application and I’m trying to find the cause of a non-reproducible error that has been reported to me. It was reported that the application suddenly stopped responding and no page could be loaded anymore. Every time this happened my customer's IT support restarted the entire server, after which the application was accessible again. It is weird because the log entries look normal up to the time of the outage and do not contain any suspicious error messages. The next available messages come from the server booting.
Said application is running in a Docker container on the production system, so my ability to change the configuration or run tests is fairly limited. I’m looking for tips on how to find and fix the cause of the problem.
This happened quite a few times over the last few weeks and the only suspicious log I could find said:

WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (15), consider raising it

Here is some information about the system:

The container image used is ubuntu:focal
Inside the container PHP-FPM 8.2.23 is running alongside with Nginx 8.2.23
The host machine is a Debian 6.1
On the host an Apache 2.4.62 passes the requests to the container

Things I already checked:

The hosts Apache logs are showing 502 status codes when the app isn’t responding, indicating to me that the Apache server isn’t the problem
The application logs show no noticeable errors, indicating that the app itself might also not be the problem
It is only necessary to restart the Docker container that is running PHP-FPM alongside the Nginx, indicating that there is no problem with the database or other services that run in their own container
The access log shows that it is not due to the same action

My next steps:

Enabling the PHP-FPM slowlog to see which actions might hang
Enabling request_terminate_timeout to terminate actions that lasts longer than the defined max_execution_time
Enabling the PHP-FPM status page to see if there are any child processes that might be hung up

Please head me in the right direction and let me now if you need further information. I’m grateful for any advice and help!

Judging by the max_children log message it would seem that the child processes are all getting hung up on something, and I would guess that it's most likely something that your application is doing. Slowlog may show you the requests that are hanging, but you're not going to be able to tell where they are hanging without building more logging/instrumentation into the app itself. You can turn on the termination timeout, but that's just going to be a band-aid solution that doesn't address the underlying cause.
